# What's the deal with the Jedi Service Corps?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

I have a few questions about the Jedi Service Corps:

1. How big was it in comparison to the "actual" Jedi Order? I think I once heard around 5000 being the number for the Jedi Order.
2. Did they just serve the Jedi, in the same way as army cooks only serving the army, or did they serve others in the galaxy? If it's the later surely they would be billions strong.
3. From what I've read you join the JSC if you either don't get chosen to become a padawan, or you fail your trials to become a knight. When this happens do you have to join the JSC or can you just make your own way in life? I know that's hard if you don't become a padawan at 13 but my point is can you leave the JSC?
4. Is it just made up of failed Jedi or are there non-force sensitives in it too?
5. What role did Jedi play in it? Workers, leaders, both?
6. Was joining the JSC the norm or was becoming a Jedi the norm

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Service_Corps